# Need assistance with a DllNotFoundExeption

Tags: c#, dll, unity-game-engine

In my project I created a Plugins folder (named it "Plugins", of course) and in it I have three plugins that get imported from my c++ project. Every time I hit build content I have my dlls show up into the "Plugins" folder.

The things is that I get a DllNotFoundExeption every time I run the game and it points to two out of my three plugins. Me and my teammates found online that you can solve this by placing the dlls in the the Assets folder. We did so, and as luck would have it, that solved it, by moving the two dlls that were giving us the error it solved it. We left the one dlls that was fine where it was inside the Plugins folder.

But something was nagging at the back of my head that this would not solve our entire issue, and I was right. When w build the game and create our executable only one dll gets built, which is the only one that is within the Plugins folder.

My question is: how do I fix my other two dlls so I don't get that DllNotFoundExeption error?

UPDATED REPORT I found that the one dll that works is done in C# while the other two that don't seem to work inside the Plugins folder are made in C++.

So my new question is how do I get Unity to accept those two dlls within the Plugins folder, or is that not possible for c++ plugins?

Comment: Are you using the [DllImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx) attribute to load the C++ dlls?

Comment: Within the c++ class, yes, yes we are.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Unity.  Are the C++ dlls managed or unmanaged?  Since Unity supports WP8 and WStore, I assume they should be managed.

Comment: We make them managed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that normally C++ Native Plugins are for Unity Pro only. That aside, there are some other ways to get it to work without a pro license as shown [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/181401-Unity-free-plugins-and-native-DLLs).

Comment: Fortunately for us we have the pro license. But this workaround is great. Though it still didn't solve the issue we are having.

Comment: Actually, I take it back. This IS one solution to our problem because their issue is similar to ours. I was just wondering what we needed to do to make unity accept our dlls within the Plugins folder. That way we don't have to manually copy the other dlls where the executable is.

Comment: @Manuel Mangual The only other thing I can suggest is compile a single assembly that includes the libraries you need. This way you have a single DLL and a wrapper for the libraries you're trying to use.